Old horror movie about people who have to stay in a mansion because of rain
I'm looking for an old horror movie that's about a bunch of people, 2 girls, a few boys (college age) and a married man and woman. 
They get stranded in the rain and have to go to a big mansion to stay. The hostess seduces one of the men and kills him at a candlelit dinner with chicken (?) and wine. The others go in their rooms and it's stuffy and the windows have bars. They see blood seeping through the ceiling and go to find out what it is and see a torture chamber with a dead black cat. Later on, a girl gets killed in there in a closing casket like thing with spikes. Her blood drains out underneath it. In the end the rest leave on a bus but it explodes.

The Devil's Nightmare from 1971.

Six of seven tourists in a east European castle overnight are victims of a helper of the devil. Is Satan willing to spare their souls? 

It ends with a bus crashing and exploding and everything else you mentioned  is there too (the dinner, the blood dripping from the ceiling and the dead black cat, the iron maiden etc.).  The movie is currently available on Youtube.
